# Find the longest path in a Tree

Tags: python-3.x, tree

```
class Tree:
def __init__(self, root, subtrees) -> None:
    """Initialize a new Tree with the given
    root value and subtrees.

    If <root> is None, the tree is empty.
    Precondition:
    - if <root> is None,
      then <subtrees> is empty.
    """
    self._root = root
    self._subtrees = subtrees

def long(self):
  """Return a list of items on the longest possible path 
  between the root of this tree and one of its leaves.

  If there is more than one path with the maximum length, 
  return the one that ends at the leaf that is furthest to the left.

  If this tree is empty, return an empty list.

  @type self: Tree 
  @rtype: list 
  """
  if len([s 
  for s in self._subtrees
  if s is not None]) == 0:
    return []
  else:
    return [self._root] + [s.long() for s in self._subtrees]
```

I'm trying to find the longest path from the root to leaf in a Tree. My code doesn't recurse until the end of the tree and returns a bunch  of empty lists. Please help.

Comment: if self._root is None:
          return []
      elif len(self._subtrees) == 0:
        return []
      else:
           return [self._root] + [subtree.long() for subtree in self._subtrees]

Comment: This helped a bit but I don't know why